# MODI Document Create path

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

I am currently working in an OCR reader using MODI dll and my code is like

```
    MODI.Document md = new MODI.Document();

    //image path 
    string fileToOCR="C:\\temp\\1in.jpg";

    md.Create(fileToOCR);
    md.OCR(MODI.MiLANGUAGES.miLANG_ENGLISH, true, true);
    MODI.Image img = (MODI.Image)md.Images[0];
    MODI.Layout layout = img.Layout;
    layout = img.Layout;
    string result = layout.Text;
    md.Close(false);
```

And I want to use

```
        //image path 
    string fileToOCR="C:\\temp\\1in.jpg";
```

to

```
        //image path 
    string fileToOCR="http://example.com/image.png";
```

How this possible, please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MODI needs a local file to work on.  You can use WebClient.DownloadData (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xz398a3f.aspx) to get the data, then save it locally.